# How can I change my bootstrap card to a bulma card

Tags: css, bulma

Using this method in `Bootstrap 5` will allow me to make each line to take 3 card:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row justify-content-center">
           {% for my_album in albums %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                   <div class="card my-2" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                             <p>{{ my_album.name }}</p>
                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'Primary-Albums' my_album.pk %}">View Album</a>
                      </div>
                  </div> 
             </div>
          {% endfor %}
       </div>
   </div>
```

I want to convert this bootstrap card into a bulma card, but i do not know how to do it, is there anyone who can show me how to do it.

What I have try, but failed:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="columns">
          {% for my_album in albums %}
          <div class="column">
               <p>{{ my_album.name }}</p>
           <a class="button is-primary" href="{% url 'Secondary-Albms' my_album.pk %}">viewAlbum</a>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
``
```

Answer (score 1):

You set your first column size and the rest fills up automatically.  So in your case `"column is-one-third"`  Your other cards should be contained within their own `<div class=column>`

```
    <div class="container">
         <div class="columns">
              {% for my_album in albums %}
              <div class="column is-one-third">
                 <div class="card">
                   <p>{{ my_album.name }}</p>
               <a class="button is-primary" href="{% url 'Secondary-Albms' my_album.pk %}">viewAlbum</a>
                 </div>
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is Bulma's code:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-one-third">is-one-third</div>
  <div class="column">Auto</div>
  <div class="column">Auto</div>
</div>
```

as per their site: [Bulma column explained](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/)